# CallableStatement with parameter names on PostgreSQL

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc

I've tried to call a stored procedure with parameter names specified, but the JDBC failed to accept the parameters. It says:

`Method org.postgresql.jdbc4.Jdbc4CallableStatement.setObject(String,Object) is not yet implemented.`

I use `postgresql-9.2-1003.jdbc4`

I there any other way to do this?

I know that I can just specify the sequence number. But I want to specify the parameter names as it is more convenient for me to do so.

My code:

```
String call_statement = "{ ? = call procedure_name(?, ?, ?) }";            
CallableStatement proc = connection.prepareCall(call_statement);
proc.registerOutParameter(1, Types.OTHER);            
proc.setObject("param1", 1);
proc.setObject("param2", "hello");
proc.setObject("param3", true);
proc.execute();
ResultSet result = (ResultSet)proc.getObject(1);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, using the parameter names is not a feature supported by the implementation of the JDBC 4 driver for the PostgreSQL database. See the [*code*](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.postgresql/postgresql/9.2-1002-jdbc4/org/postgresql/jdbc3/AbstractJdbc3Statement.java#AbstractJdbc3Statement.setObject%28java.lang.String,java.lang.Object%29) of this JDBC 4 implementation in [GrepCode](http://grepcode.com/).

However, you can still continue to use an integer (variable or literal) to indicate the position of the parameter.

Comment: Aww..what a bummer. Has this feature never been implemented before?

Comment: PostgreSQL has not implemented all features of JDBC 4. Apparently, Oracle and IBM have this feature implemented.

Comment: Just an update for those passing by, unless I'm mistaken, I have encountered the same error with PostgreSQL 9.6 with the 42.1.2 JDBC driver

Answer (score 2):

It's 2020 here and the standard open source JDBC driver for Postgres still doesn't support named parameter notation for `CallableStatement`.

Interestingly, *EnterpriseDB* driver [*does* support it](https://www.enterprisedb.com/edb-docs/d/edb-postgres-connectors/user-guides/jdbc-guide/11.0.1/EDB_Postgres_Advanced_Server_JDBC_Connector_Guide.1.22.html) (with that said - I tried to use EDB JDBC driver - it indeed supports named parameters but it does so many things differently, if at all, that we ruled out this option entirly, for those other reasons)

A solution which worked for us - is to use this "hack" (pseudo-code, YMMV):

```
String sql = "SELECT * FROM PROC(IN_PARAM1 => ?, IN_PARAM2 => ?, IN_PARAM => ?)";            
PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
ps.setObject("IN_PARAM1", 1);
ps.setObject("IN_PARAM2", "hello");
ps.setObject("IN_PARAM3", true);
ps.execute();
ResultSet result = (ResultSet)ps.getObject(1);
```

The killer feature of this notation - is the ability to call SPs with optional params (it could be achieved by having optional *ordinal* params, but if you have more than a few of them - it becomes a nightmare, as one needs to pass so many `nulls`, that it's too easy to miscount, and those are very hard to spot)

There are also additional benefits, like ability to return multiple `ResultSets` (refcursors), ability to use maps as params, etc.

P.S.: we also use the same trick for `Node.js` with `node-postgres` - works well for years.